# Attempting to Use FindOne Mongoose method with EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am attempting to use the mongoose `findOne` method with my date model property to only use the data from my most recent document. I am using the EJS templating system and was trying to use this method with my view, but receiving an error, `} has no method 'findOne' at my`events.findOne` line. How should I be using this method? Should it be called in the routes.js instead?

eventsModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    title: String,
    company: String,
    url: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    upcomingEvent: { type: Boolean, default: false }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Event = require('./models/eventsModel');



//GET '/'
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/index.ejs');
});

//GET '/about'
router.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/about.ejs');
});



//GET '/media'
router.get('/media', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/media.ejs');
});

router.route('/admin/events/create')

    .post(function(req, res){

        var events = new Event();

        events.name = req.body.name;
        events.title = req.body.title;
        events.company = req.body.company;
        events.url = req.body.url;
        events.upcomingEvent = req.body.upcomingEvent;

        events.save(function(err){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.redirect(303, '/events');

        });
    })

    .get(function(req, res){
        Event.find(function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.render('pages/events-create.ejs');
        });
    });

router.route('/admin/events/:events_id')

    .get(function(req, res){
        Event.findById(req.params.events_id, function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(events);
        });
    })

    .put(function(req, res){

        Event.findById(req.params.events_id, function(err, events){
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Event Updated'});
        });
    });

//GET '/events'
router.get('/events', function(req, res){

    Event.find(function(err, events){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        events.name = req.body.name;
        events.title = req.body.title;
        events.company = req.body.company;
        events.url = req.body.url;
        events.upcomingEvent = req.body.upcomingEvent;

        res.render('pages/events.ejs', {
            events : events
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router; //export all objects in router module
```

events.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>
    <% include ../partials/navigation %>

    <div class="grid" id="lvc-events-title-container">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div id="events-heading">
                <h1><i>-EVENTS</i></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid" id="lvc-current-event-container">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div id="current-event">
                <% events.findOne({'events.date': -1}, function(events) { %>
                <h2><i>-UPCOMING SPEAKER</i></h2>
                <div id="current-event-image">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="speaker-image">
                    <h3>John Doe</h3>
                    <p>Title</p>
                    <p>Company</p>

                    <% }); %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="grid" id="lvc-past-events-container">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div id="past-speakers">
            <h2><i>-PAST SPEAKERS</i></h2>
            <% events.forEach(function(events) { %>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<%= events.url %>"><%= events.name %></a> (<%= events.title %> | <%= events.company %>)</li>
            </ul>
            <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as far as i can see `events` in the view is wrapped object array. It is javascript array, and you can use `filter` instead of `findOne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, few little weridnesses from what I can tell...

1. Querying from views isn't a great idea. You should be performing the query in your 'controller' or route.
2. The method `findOne` is a `static` method on the Model (like find i.e. `Event.find`), not an `instance` method on a document (like save i.e. `event.save`)
3. You setting properties on an array returned from the `find` method
4. You just need to order your query ;D

Router:

```
router.get('/events', function(req, res) {
    Event.find({})
        .sort({'date': -1})
        .exec(function(err, events) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // Events is an array of event models, so this is setting properties on an array
        // It also doesn't look like you are using it in your view so its not needed
        //events.name = req.body.name;
        //events.title = req.body.title;
        //events.company = req.body.company;
        //events.url = req.body.url;
        //events.upcomingEvent = req.body.upcomingEvent;


        // The events local in your page will be an array with index[0] being the most recent event, which I believe is your 'UPCOMING SPEAKER'. You can then loop over the rest of the array from 1.
        res.render('pages/events.ejs', {
            events : events
        });
    });
});
```

View

```
<div class="grid" id="lvc-current-event-container">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div id="current-event">
            <h2><i>-UPCOMING SPEAKER</i></h2>
            <div id="current-event-image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="speaker-image">
                <h3><%= events[0].name %></h3>
                <p><%= events[0].title %></p>
                <p><%= events[0].compant %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
<div class="grid" id="lvc-past-events-container">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div id="past-speakers">
        <h2><i>-PAST SPEAKERS</i></h2>
        <% for (var i = 1; i < events.length; i++) { %>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%= events[i].url %>"><%= events[i].name %></a> (<%= events[i].title %> | <%= events[i].company %>)</li>
        </ul>
        <% }; %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Mongoose very extensively, but when you pass the 'events' array to your template, you're already passing the latest event (plus the previous events) implicitly - meaning you just need to massage the data a little bit to display it in the desired manner. Note: you might be better-served by the [all](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-all) method, since it doesn't look like you're doing any filtering on the events.

This code might not work and assumes the data in the events array is sorted by date (treat it like pseudo-code), but it should set you on the right track.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>
    <% include ../partials/navigation %>

<div class="grid" id="lvc-events-title-container">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div id="events-heading">
            <h1><i>-EVENTS</i></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid" id="lvc-current-event-container">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div id="current-event">
            <h2><i>-UPCOMING SPEAKER</i></h2>
            <div id="current-event-image">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="speaker-image">
                <h3><%= events[0].name %></h3>
                <p><%= events[0].title %></p>
                <p><%= events[0].company %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="grid" id="lvc-past-events-container">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div id="past-speakers">
        <h2><i>-PAST SPEAKERS</i></h2>
        <% for (var i = 1; i < events.length; i++) { %>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%= events[i].url %>"><%= events[i].name %></a> (<%= events[i].title %> | <%= events[i].company %>)</li>
        </ul>
        <% }; %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```